# Using JavaScript's Array.splice with assigning the replacements item as an array

Tags: javascript

I've got to delete / replace elements in an array.
For accomplishing these task one usually uses Array.splice().

Problem: Array.splice() expects the replacement items as a comma separated list. But I got the values as an array. I've made this 
helper function which makes it possible to use splice with an array instead of single values.

```
    // Deletes elements in an array and 
    // replaces the elements with other
    // values. 
    // -- Parameter -------------------
    // 1. Array - The array from which 
    // elements shall be deleted.
    // 2. Number - The index at which to
    // start the deletion.
    // 3. Number - The count of elements
    // to delete.
    // 4. Array - The elements to insert
    // into the target array.
    // -- Return ----------------------
    // Array - The deleted elements.

    function replaceArrayElements(
                                   targetArray,
                                   startIndex,
                                   deleteCount, 
                                   replacements ) {
    // 1. Parameter of .apply():
    //   Defining the context (this-keyword).
    // 2. Parameter: 
    //   a.) Start with the element startIndex.
    //   b.) Delete 3 elements.
    //   c.) Put these elements into the array
    //   as new values.
    //   a.), b.), c.) concated together
    //   into one array. The array is then
    //   used as the parameters of .splice().
    return Array.prototype.splice.apply(
                 targetArray, 
                 [startIndex, deleteCount].concat(replacements));
    }

    // -------- TEST ---------------------------------
    var test = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      test.push(i);
    }

    console.log('Before insert: %o', test);

    var ret = 
      replaceArrayElements(test, 5, 3, ['Six', 'Seven', 'Eight']);

    console.log('After insert: %o', test);
    console.log('Return: %o', ret);
    // -- RESULTS -----
    // Before insert: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    // After insert: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 9, 10]
    // Return: [6, 7, 8]
```

The function does as expected. 
But anyway: If someone knows a better way to accomplish the task then please let me know. The same for improvement suggestions.

Comment: You could add a type-check for `targetArray` and `replacements` like this: `if (Object.prototype.toString.call(targetArray) !== "[object Array]") throw "targetArray is not of the type array!";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks straightforward and solid under ES5. I have no comments or criticism for that.

However, under ES6, there's the **[spread operator](https://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/spread_operator)** (which is relatively well supported in most modern browsers, and in Babel), with which you can effectively oneline the whole thing like so:

```
targetArray.splice(start, end, ...replacements);
```